# Get first div contents only rather than all with same class

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am having three divs each with class myDiv(just for example). And each of div has unordered list with list items inside it.

So i can write down xpath as

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='myDiv']/ul/li")
```

I want the first myDiv only.

But this will give results of all three divs. How to get only first div contents. Please help to modify this xpath.

Comment: How about trying `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='myDiv']/ul/li"));`? Don't use `findElements`.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Am using this only . List<WebElement> AllItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='gbwshoveler-content']/ul/li"));

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Point is I want only first div content rather than all three

Comment: The first line what I had given will work. But if you want to fetch from the list then use this `AllItems.get(0);` Here is the doc [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))

Comment: Let me know if this helps. I'll post it as my answer then.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro Hey If I do AllItems.get(0); I will get first list item only.

Comment: The answer given below should solve your issue.

Comment: Try By.xpath("(//div[@class='myDiv'])[1]/ul/li")

Comment: @SIslam Still same results :(. If say we have 6 list items under one MyDiv. Am getting 18 list items . By using By.xpath("(//div[@class='myDiv'])[1]/ul/li")

Comment: Then By.xpath("//div[@class='myDiv']/ul[position() = 1]/li")

Comment: @SIslam Still same :( 18 am getting

Comment: better to share html / site:)

Comment: @SIslam http://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox/ref=nav_topnav_deals?gb_hero_f_100=p:1,c:all,s:missed Under div "gbwshoveler-content" there are 3 different UL. I want only first one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93339/discussion-between-sislam-and-gitcoder).

Answer (score 1):

As discussed with the OP, following are potential xpaths to go with.

```
//li[contains(@id,'100_deal')]
(//div[@class='gbwshoveler-content'])[position()=1]
//div [@id="deals-onethirtyfive-hero10903707629515"]//ul/li
(//div[@class='gbwshoveler-content'])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get first div using
`By.xpath("//div[@class='myDiv'][1]/ul/li")`

Comment: Still getting all div results :(

Comment: Still same results :(. If say we have 6 list items under one MyDiv. Am getting 18 list items . By using By.xpath("(//div[@class='myDiv'])[1]/ul/li")

Comment: @GitCoder `By.xpath("(//div[@class='myDiv'])[1]/ul/li")` should work if you have only three div. 
can you share your html code

Comment: if your code contains three parent tag and each have three different 'myDiv' in that case above xpath will not work.so,if there is any parent tag you can try by apply same.

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox/ref=nav_topnav_deals?gb_hero_f_100=p:1,c:all,s:missed Under div "gbwshoveler-content" there are 3 different UL. I want only first one. Can you now better tell.

Comment: @GitCoder try this `//div[@class='gbox-section-featured']//div[@class='gbwshoveler-content']//li `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93368/discussion-between-devang-thakrar-and-gitcoder).